# Can I install Ubuntu desktop in Intel Core i3 N305 8 core Processor (8 GB/512 GB SSD)?

Tags: system-installation

I am planning to buy new laptop having Intel Core i3 N305 8 core Processor (8 GB/512 GB SSD), and use Ubuntu desktop in it.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you can, since I use an intel i3 7th gen, 4GB RAM, 512 GB SSD and it works perfectly fine, and smoothly without any issues.

There are the following specs:
Hardware Model: Dell Inc. Inspiron 3584
Memory: 4 GiB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i3-7020U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4
Graphics: Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2F)
Disk Capacity: 512.1 GB

(Windows lied to me about my RAM and ROM capacities, the values in the first paragraph were what my old windows said to me)

Comment: Thanks Zayaan for the reply, please let me know is your i3 7th gen process is above <=2GHz.. as I checked the minimum requirement for ubuntu is 2 GHz and The processor i3 N305 is having 1.8 - 3.8 GHz.  the N305 is launched this year Jan 2023 but want to make sure the ubuntu will get install on it or not, as per that will purchase the laptop.